Dask worker nodes and multiprocessing raising TypeError during object initialization
I have a program that I wrote. I define a class in this program that is a subclass of a class I import. If I run this code without Dask, I successfully run it. When I plug in Dask, I get an error saying TypeError('object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)') on the super() call. I suspect there's some issue in worker initialization, but I'm not sure what I need to initialize in my worker code vs in my master code.
A basic outline of my code:
import foo

class myFoo(foo):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

...

cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)

...

def submit(seed, **p)
  ...
  myFoo(seed=seed, bar=bar, baz=baz)

...

for p in param_list:
  futures.extend(client.map(submit, seeds, **p))


This is also happening when I use multiprocessing.
